# After you finish sleep, or After you'll be finished sleeping - or is there some other way of phrasing this correctly?

Tags: future-tense

I have called my English friend and now she is sleeping.

So how can I say

> After you finish sleep call me please.

and be grammatically correct?

Something like this maybe?

> After you'll be finished sleeping, call me please.

or just use simple tense?

P.S My friend is from Indonesia but we both talk in English.

Comment: How about: When you wake up, please call me.  OR, When you're finished sleeping, please call me.  OR After you've slept, please call me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, "sleep" is a noun and needs to use the gerund to change it into a noun...

> "After you finish sleep**ing**, call me please".

In your second example, you have incorrectly used the future tense of *to be*.  The apropriate conjugation is the present tense, *are*, because your friend is presently sleeping...

> after you're finished sleeping, call me please

Answer (score 1):

We can express the idea in many ways. Here are a few, each with a different verb structure.

> When you wake up, call me.
>
> When you are awake, call me.
>
> When you have woken up, call me.
>
> When you have awoken, call me.
>
> When you finish sleeping, call me.
>
> When you are done sleeping, call me.
>
> When you have had your nap, call me.   [if it is a brief sleep during the day]
>
> When you are done with your nap, call me.
>
> When you have finished your nap, call me.
>
> When you are finished napping, call me.
>
> When your nap's over, call me.